# SSRS Report Builder calculated fields with SQL table (attribute-value)

Tags: reporting-services, field, average

I have a SQL database for monthly values with some valuetypeline and value for each month and the problem is when i tried to aggregate the information in the tablix matrix inside an ssrs report

Example of the database

```
CustomerId | Year | Month | ValueTypeId | Value
---------------------------------------------
     1     | 2020 |    1  |      1      | 500  
     1     | 2020 |    1  |      2      | 10  
     1     | 2020 |    2  |      1      | 200
     1     | 2020 |    2  |      2      | 15
     2     | 2020 |    1  |      1      | 100  
     2     | 2020 |    1  |      2      | 10  
     2     | 2020 |    2  |      1      | 1500
     2     | 2020 |    2  |      2      | 15
```

And i have created an example of datalabel field for a specific valuetypeid taking into account 2 parameters that i have (Year and Month)

> =IIF(Fields!ValueTypeId Value="1" and Fields!Year.Value=Parameters!Year.Value and
> Fields!Month.Value=Parameters!Month.Value,CDbl(Fields!ReportingValue.Value),CDbl(0))

When i create a tablix matrix and I put the fields with [Sum(SalesMTD)] imagine Year =2020 and month = 2, the result will be 200+1500 = 1700

And if I create the same table than the example adding the nuew field, the result is something like this.

```
CustomerId | Year | Month | ValueTypeId | Value | SalesMTD
-----------------------------------------------------------
     1     | 2020 |    1  |      1      | 500   | 0  
     1     | 2020 |    1  |      2      | 10    | 0  
     1     | 2020 |    2  |      1      | 200   | 200
     1     | 2020 |    2  |      2      | 15    | 0
     2     | 2020 |    1  |      1      | 100   | 0 
     2     | 2020 |    1  |      2      | 10    | 0  
     2     | 2020 |    2  |      1      | 1500  | 1500
     2     | 2020 |    2  |      2      | 15    | 0
```

The problem is when we tried to calculate an average [Avg(SalesMTD)] becasue the system instead of doing this (200+1500)/2 it seams to doing (0+0+200+0+0+0+1500+0)/8. Something that it is wrong for me.

Can someone helpme on this? I have tried averageiff innoring 0 values but i cant finde it, in any case 0 could be a possible value if it is real, i think that the problem is more in the calculation of the field that put 0 in the rows that are not with the conditions when in reality should be ignored or nulls. For sums is valid but i have found that for average or other calculations is not correct.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It could be possible to use as field this calculatation?

=IIF(Fields!ValueTypeId Value="1" and Fields!Year.Value=Parameters!Year.Value and Fields!Month.Value=Parameters!Month.Value,CDbl(Fields!ReportingValue.Value),Nothing)

I'm trying and it seems to work but i dont know if it has bad consequences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem, are you pointed out is that the `AVG()` function includes zeros. However, it does not include `Null` values.

So, if we convert zeros to null values (`Nothing` in SSRS expressions) then we can fix your issue.

Use the following expression

```
=Avg(
    IIF(Fields!SalesMTD.Value=0, Nothing, Fields!SalesMTD.Value)
    )
```

In the screen shot below, I took your sample data and added a SUM, a standard AVG and finally the expression above (labelled AGV2).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you are right. i didnt know the Nothing function and it is what i need.

i have used

=iif(CDbl(Fields!ReportingValue.Value)=Nothing, Nothing,
IIF(Fields!ValueTypeId Value="1" and Fields!Year.Value=Parameters!Year.Value and Fields!Month.Value=Parameters!Month.Value,CDbl(Fields!ReportingValue.Value),CDbl(0)))

to create the fields and then when i use the avg, everhthing go properly. 

Many thanks